# Change color of part of Material Icon

Tags: html, css, google-material-icons

I would like to change only **part of the color of Material icons** (from google) like in the image. In the image it only shows the bottom bar changing color, not the entire A.

I went to several questions that **only showed how to change the entire color** of the materialize icon.[image: only changes bottom bar]

I realize that I can use svg, and I can break the image up into different paths and then specify the color of each of them as stated in jdnz's answer.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
  <path d="M5 17v2h14v-2z" fill="#00FFFF"/>
  <path d="M12 5.98L13.87 11h-3.74zM9.5 12.8h5l.9 2.2h2.1L12.75 4h-1.5L6.5 15h2.1z"/>
  <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

However, I have several images, and I don't want to create many svg's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use svg you can break the image up into different paths and then specify the color of each of them.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
  <path d="M5 17v2h14v-2z" fill="#00FFFF"/>
  <path d="M12 5.98L13.87 11h-3.74zM9.5 12.8h5l.9 2.2h2.1L12.75 4h-1.5L6.5 15h2.1z"/>
  <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```