# compose modifiy icon set part of the color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I have an icon to indicate sequence. [image]

My requirement is that when the order is reversed, the lower half of the icon turns blue; when the order is turned, the upper half of the icon turns blue.

I found a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436491/change-color-of-part-of-material-icon), but it conflicts with my needs in two points. First, I don't know how to write such code in compose. Second, I prefer to use code to control the color transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using BlendModes you can manipulate any pixel using another shape, png file, drawing or Path. You can refer these answers for more details

[Jetpack Compose Applying PorterDuffMode to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653560/jetpack-compose-applying-porterduffmode-to-image)

[How to clip or cut a Composable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73590695/how-to-clip-or-cut-a-composable/73590696#73590696)

Result

[image]

Implementation

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .drawWithContent {
                val height = size.height

                with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
                    val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

                    // Destination
                    drawContent()

                    // Source
                    drawRect(
                        Color.Red,
                        topLeft = Offset(0f, height / 2),
                        size = Size(size.width, size.height / 2),
                        blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn

                    )

                }
            },
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.arrows),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

Comment: In this answer rectangle is clipped to shape of downwards arrow or pixels of both are combined using source(rectangle) pixels while using destination shape