# How can I create a typing animation without compose state(draw state) in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

At the moment, this recomposes whenever the caretIndex changes. But, I found out this can lead UI freezing.

```
    Text(
        text = buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = color)) {
                append(text.substring(0, caretIndex))
            }
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Transparent)) {
                append(text.substring(caretIndex, text.length))
            }
        },
        style = style,
        modifier = modifier
    )
```

And I found out there are three steps, compose-layout-drawing from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMKMwh9gZuI) and [this best practice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOQB8PTLkpY)

So, I am trying to fix this within draw state. But, `drawBehind` seems like it only draws behind the actual UI. And, I found `graphicsLayer` and I think it works in draw state. But this doesn't give any feature that I can show the text one by one.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`Modifier.drawWithContent{}` with `drawContent()` draws your content. Depending on order of `drawContent()` you can draw behind or in front of actual content. You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75725308/how-to-create-vectordrawable-with-gradient-and-multiple-colors-with-jetpack-comp/75725309#75725309) for sample usage. I draw a rectangle with blend mode above actual heart or clock drawable in that answer.