Apply brush on custom background in canvas. Jetpack compose
I wonder how can I apply gradient on my custom background made from SVG in Jetpack Compose. I tried every blend mode available, and changed order of drawing, and it is not helping.
  val vector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.drawing_cropped)
    val vectorPainter = rememberVectorPainter(image = vector)
    val brush = Brush.linearGradient(
        colors = listOf(
            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer
        )
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            .wrapContentSize()
            .drawBehind {
                with(vectorPainter) {
                    draw(size)
                    drawRect(
                        brush = brush,
                        size = size,
                        blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
                    )
                }
            }
    )

This code gives me background of rectangle shape with needed brush. Other blend modes could give needed shape (destionation), but not brush colored. Hue just creates one-colored background with destination
I tried every blend mode available, and changed order of drawing, and it is not helping.

You can refer this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75725308/how-to-create-vectordrawable-with-gradient-and-multiple-colors-with-jetpack-comp/75725309#75725309
